# Stop Monodevelop from removing white spaces from line after writing a semicolon

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, formatting, monodevelop

I like to vertically align my code and Monodevelop (v 5.9.6) automatically removes white spaces from my lines of code after I put a semicolon.

Ex :

```
string other = "something";
int    jad   = 9
```

becomes :

```
string other = "something";
int jad = 9;
```

What's worse, hitting undo will undo the whole thing, not just the semicolon like in most editors (which just undo the formatting) so I have to place the semicolon and then vertically align so that it leaves it.

Is there an option to stop this behaviour?

Comment: Is this the Mac version? I can't even get it to do what you're describing using the Win version (5.9.6).

Comment: @RichJoslin It's the Windows version.  It wasn't doing this previously or at the very least, it would allow me to ctrl-Z out of it doing the formatting while leaving the semicolon.  It's Monodevelop-Unity edition if that has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're on MacOS, there's a section under Preferences called **Source Code**. In there is a subsection called **Code Formatting** and there you'll find the choice **C# source code**. In the right half of the preferences window, you'll see a *Policy* menu and two tabs **Text Style** and **C# Format**. Clicking the *Edit* button under **C# Format** will show you a lot of things you can tweak. But your particular coding preference is not possible I'm afraid.